# Python Nose Framework: How to stop execution after N failures

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I know that nose has the -x and --stop flags to stop after the first test failure, but for the code base I am working with tests usually fail in groups of 3-4. A relevant error message may only be in one or two of those tests, so exiting after the first error could mean that I may need to run the tests again.

Is there a way, possibly with a command line flag or a nose plugin, to stop test execution after N failures?